# How is the model method called in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just inherited a CI project and am trying to figure out some things. One of the problems I'm facing is the following:

Given these 2 links:

```
/esales/index.php/sales/send_receipt

/esales/index.php/sales/run
```

I was looking through the CI project and noted this file:

Inside `esales/application/models/sale.php`, there were 2 functions that were executed, mainly:

```
class sale_model extends CI_Model{
  public function get_sales_data(){ /* gets sales data */}
  public function send_invoice(){ /* sends order receipt */}
```

And the idea is that when the user clicks `/index.php/sales/run`, the function `get_sales_data()` is run and when `/index.php/sales/send_receipt` is clicked, `send_invoice()` is run.

How does CodeIgniter connect the link to the native method in the model? In particular, how does CI know that `/sales/` get translated to the `sales_model` PHP object?

Comment: You should read the framework's [manual](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/) ... This is a really basic thing, you're doomed to failure if you can't get to it by yourself.

Comment: shocked that no one has mentioned the router yet. application/config/routes otherwise do the tutorial right away - and don't just read it - actually work through it so you really understand. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the sales.php file in controller..which may contain "send_receipt", "run" methods. probably the model functions are called in those controller..

Answer (score 0):

**Model and View cannot be access without the command of controller**. That's what we called [MVC Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Your `get_sales_data` and `send_invoice` will not called automatcally/independantly  unless your controller called it.

Check your controller you have these kind of code.

```
class Sales extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->load->model('sale_model'); #load model
        $this->sale_model->get_sales_data(); # access data
    }

    public function send_receipt()
    {
        $this->load->model('sale_model'); # load model
        $this->sale_model->send_invoice(); # access data
    }

}
```

Comment: If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)